# React / Node : How to create a form with file upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, upload, multer

I'm trying to make a form with a file upload then send them to the database. I created the api as well as the multer configuration, but new to react I don't know how to implement it in the front. Everything was going fine until I tried to upload an image.

the multer config :

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES = {
'image/jpg': 'jpg',
'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
'image/png': 'png'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, callback) =\> {
callback(null, 'images');
},
filename: (req, file, callback) =\> {
const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('\_');
const extension = MIME_TYPES\[file.mimetype\];
callback(null, name + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
}
});

module.exports = multer({storage}).single('image');
```

The controller :

```
const Realisation = require('../models/Realisation');
const fs = require('fs')

exports.createRealisation = (req, res, next) =\> {
const realisationObject = JSON.parse(req.body.realisation);
delete realisationObject.\_id;
delete realisationObject.\_userId;
const realisation = new Realisation({
...realisationObject,
userId: req.auth.userId,
imageUrl: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`
});
realisation.save()
.then(() =\> res.status(201).json({ message: 'Objet enregistré !'}))
.catch(error =\> res.status(400).json({ error }));
};

exports.modifyRealisation = (req, res, next) =\> {
let realisationObject = {};
req.file ? (

    Realisation.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
    }).then((realisation) => {
      
      const filename = realisation.picture.split('/images/')[1]
      fs.unlinkSync(`images/${filename}`)
    }),
    realisationObject = {
     
      ...JSON.parse(req.body.realisation),
      picture: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${
        req.file.filename
      }`,
    }

) : (
realisationObject = {
...req.body
}
)

Realisation.updateOne(

      {
        _id: req.params.id
      }, {
        ...realisationObject,
        _id: req.params.id
      }
    )
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Realisation modifiée !'
    }))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({
      error
    }))

}

exports.deleteRealisation = (req, res, next) =\> {

Realisation.findOne({
\_id: req.params.id
})
.then(realisation =\> {

      const filename = realisation.picture.split('/images/')[1];
     
      fs.unlink(`images/${filename}`, () => {
        
        Realisation.deleteOne({
            _id: req.params.id
          })
          .then(() => res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Realisation supprimée !'
          }))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).json({
            error
          }));
      });
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json({
      error
    }));

};

exports.getOneRealisation =(req, res, next) =\> {
Realisation.findOne({ \_id: req.params.id })
.then(realisation =\> res.status(200).json(realisation))
.catch(error =\> res.status(404).json({ error }));
};

exports.getAllRealisations = (req, res, next) =\> {
Realisation.find()
.then(realisations =\> res.status(200).json(realisations))
.catch(error =\> res.status(400).json({ error }));
};
```

The model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const sanitizerPlugin = require('mongoose-sanitizer-plugin');

const realisationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true},
description: { type: String, required: true},
videoUrl: { type: String, required: true },
picture: {type: String, required: true },
});

realisationSchema.plugin(sanitizerPlugin);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Realisation', realisationSchema);\`
```

The route :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const multer = require('../middleware/multer-config');
const realisationCtrl = require('../controllers/realisation');

router.post('/', auth, multer, realisationCtrl.createRealisation);
router.put('/:id', auth, multer, realisationCtrl.modifyRealisation);
router.delete('/:id', auth, multer, realisationCtrl.deleteRealisation);
router.get('/:id', auth, multer, realisationCtrl.getOneRealisation);
router.get('/', auth, multer, realisationCtrl.getAllRealisations);

module.exports = router;
```

The path in the app.js :

```
app.use('/api/showreel', showreelRoutes);
app.use('/api/realisation', realisationRoutes);
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', userRoutes);
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(\__dirname, 'images')));\`
```

The front :

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function AddRealisation() {
const \[name, setName\] = React.useState("");
const \[description, setDescription\] = React.useState("");
const \[videoUrl, setVideoUrl\] = React.useState("");
const \[picture, setPicture\] = React.useState("");
const navigate = useNavigate();

const fileOnchange = (event) =\> {
setPicture(event.target.files\[0\]);
};

const sendPicture = (event) =\> {
let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("image", picture);
    
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/images`, {
      method: "Post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resBody) => {
        console.log(resBody);
      });

};

const addRealisation = async () =\> {
console.warn(name, description, videoUrl, picture);
const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).userId;
console.warn(userId);
let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/realisation", {
method: "post",
body: JSON.stringify({ name, description, videoUrl, picture }),
headers: {
"Content-type": "application/json",
},
});
result = await result.json();
console.warn(result);
if (result) {
sendPicture();
navigate("/realisation");
}
};
return (
\<div className="realisation"\>
<h1>Add Réalisation</h1>
\<input
type="texte"
placeholder="Enter realisation name"
className="inputBox"
onChange={(e) =\> setName(e.target.value)}
/\>
\<input
type="texte"
placeholder="Enter description"
className="inputBox"
onChange={(e) =\> setDescription(e.target.value)}
/\>
\<input
type="texte"
placeholder="Enter URL of the video"
className="inputBox"
onChange={(e) =\> setVideoUrl(e.target.value)}
/\>
\<input type="file" onChange={fileOnchange} /\>

      <button onClick={addRealisation} className="appButton">
        Add
      </button>
    </div>

);
}

export default AddRealisation;\`
```

And I created a folder for the pictures.

[image]

I currently have this error message :

[image]

Again I think it's a rookie mistake, thanks for your answers